# I want to generate a varchar code with mysql

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, ascii, auto-generate

I want to generate a code with mysql something like 'B45'. the generation starts at 'A0' and ends in 'Y99'
, but somehow there is a problem, please I need help with my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER oeuvre_code BEFORE INSERT ON oeuvres
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(select * from oeuvres) THEN
            SET @code2 ='A0';
        ELSE
            SET @test = (select code from oeuvres LIMIT 1);
            SET @char =(select left (@test,1));
            SET @nbr = select substr(@test,2);
            if @char!='Z' AND @nbr+0 <99 THEN
                set @char2 = select (ASCII(@char)+1);
                set @nbr2 = @nbr+1;</i>

            END IF;
            set @code2=@char2+@nbr2;
            INSERT INTO oeuvres VALUES(NEW.Id,NEW.Toile,NEW.Description,NEW.Prix,NEW.Date,NEW.Etat,@code2);
        END IF;
    END;
```

Here is the problem I get:

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


CREATE TRIGGER oeuvre_code BEFORE INSERT ON oeuvres
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(select * from oeuvres) THEN
            SET @code2 ='A0'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(select * from oeuvres) THEN
            SET @code2' at line 2
```

[Picture of the problem I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnbHB.png)

Comment: And what's that problem?

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(select * from oeuvres) THEN
            SET @code2' at line 2